# Issue with .equals()

Tags: java, split, equals

Following is a small section of the code I am using, along with the syntax of the text file I am using. (I am fairly sure both are grossly overcomplicated, but I am not exactly sure how to simplify them.)

```
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {

            if(line.split("@@")[0].equals(lineNumber))
            {
                numberOfLines = Integer.parseInt(line.split("@@")[1]);
                spaceSkip = 1;
                worked = 0;
            }

            if(spaceSkip == 0)
            {
                if(numberOfLines > 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    numberOfLines--;
                }
            }

            spaceSkip = 0;
        }
```

And the format of the text file is: 
1@@2@@3@@0
Text goes below it,
and can span multiple lines.

The 3 and 0 do not come into play here. The intent is for the program to search for the number selected and match it to the first number, 1 in this case. The second number is the number of lines to read. In the code, I have "spaceSkip" so that it does not read the indexing line.

Explanations aside, the issue I am having is that `line.split("@@")[0].equals(lineNumber)` seems to be reading false. I have printed both out to the screen at the same time, and both equal 1, but it is still returning an error message I included. ("worked = 0;" is what keeps the error from triggering.) I am certain it is a stupidly simple mistake I am making here, but I still am unable to figure it out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, including the text file.

Comment: Most of these variables are not declared here. It's hard to debug if we don't have enough information.

Comment: I would guess that lineNumber is not declared as a string, and you are comparing the string from the split to a java.lang.Integer. which will always return false. but without declarations it is just a guess.

Comment: Majority of the variables are not displayed here. Plus When you share your code please remember to share the fully complete code or else it is difficult to debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a comparison doesn't return what you think it should, check that the types are what you think they are.

String#split returns an array of Strings. For your given input the first element of that array will be "1". If lineNumber is something other than a String, say an int, then equals will still work (the primitive int gets autoboxed to a java.lang.Integer, which is a subclass of java.lang.Object, which is the type the equals method takes as a parameter), but the comparison (`"1".equals(1)`) will always return false. JavaScript is OK with equating a string and an int (`"1" == 1` returns true), but Java is not.

The easiest fix would be to convert the lineNumber to a String, by calling String#valueOf passing in lineNumber. It would be better to convert lineNumber to a String than try to convert the split output to an Integer, because the Integer parsing could fail on bad input, and I'd rather avoid having to manage that possibility.

The cut-n-pasting of the split call is unfortunate mostly because of redundancy, you should do the split once into a local variable like:

```
String[] parts = line.split("@@");
if (parts[0].equals("1")) {
    numberOfLines = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    ...
```

Comment: Well, dang. When I entered the value for lineNumber, I put 1, instead of "1". I feel immensely stupid now, it was as simple as that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the initialization of the variables it is hard to tell, but it is possible that you are comparing a String to an Integer in this if statement.
You may want to try casting the second argument to a String as follows.

```
if(line.split("@@")[0].equals(String.valueOf(lineNumber)))
```

Comment: Well, I guess it would be safer to use `String.valueOf(lineNumber)` instead, to avoid a `NumberFormatException` if `line.split("@@")[0]` is not a number.